# In Windows Command prompt, how can I run one command if there is no input, and another if there is, within a certain time?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I wasn't sure how to phrase the question, but here's what I want to do.

If a server process closes (determined by "`ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul`"), I want to prompt the user to press any key to close the server, but if the user doesn't press a key have the server run again. Here is my current script:

```
@echo off
:start
echo (%time%) Server started.
"C:\jdk1.7.0_72\bin\java.exe" -server -d64 -Xmx4G -Xms1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Xmn512M -jar spigot.jar nogui
echo (%time%) WARNING: Server closed or crashed, restarting.
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
timeout 15
goto start
```

As you see, I have the restart function already, and it works perfectly. So to clarify: if the user presses a key, the server closes and does not restart. If the user does not press a key, after 15 seconds the server starts again.

Comment: `ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul&&pause&&taskkill /im java* /f` ?

Comment: What would this do? I also need to save the program before shutting it down.

Comment: You could try [sleepx.exe](http://www.westmesatech.com/sst.html), which delays for a specified time and returns a non-zero exit code if a key is pressed before the time elapses.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to detect if TIMEOUT counted down to 0, or if the user pressed a key. As long as the timeout interval is >= 10, then the last two characters printed will always be " 0" if TIMEOUT finished counting down. So you simply need to capture the output with a FOR /F command and test the last two characters.

The only potential problem is that you will no longer see the countdown on the screen.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('timeout 15') do set "test=%%A"
if "%test:~-2%" equ " 0" (
  echo The user did NOT press a key
) else (
  echo The user pressed a key
)
```

If the timeout interval is < 10, then you only check the last character to see if it is 0.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('timeout 5') do set "test=%%A"
if "%test:~-1%" equ "0" (
  echo The user did NOT press a key
) else (
  echo The user pressed a key
)
```

Regarding how to incorporate this into your code - I'm not positive, because I don't fully understand what your code is supposed to do.

Your PING command cannot possibly determine if the server is down, nor can it shut the server down. All it does is introduce a 3 second delay into your script.

If you want to loop back to :start if TIMEOUT completed without the user pressing a key, then all you need is:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('timeout 15') do set "test=%%A"
if "%test:~-2%" equ " 0" goto start
```

Comment: So how do I implement this into the current batch file?

Comment: @A.J.Ruckman - I fixed my logic a bit, and suggested how you might incorporate it into your script.

Comment: Thanks a ton, now I got it to work. Here is the script:

`@echo off
:start
echo (%time%) Server started.
"C:\jdk1.7.0_72\bin\java.exe" -server -d64 -Xmx4G -Xms1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Xmn512M -jar spigot.jar nogui
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('timeout 15') do set "test=%%A"
if "%test:~-2%" equ " 0" (
  goto start
) else (
  exit
)`

Answer (score 0):

`timeout`does not return an `errorlevel` [Request for inclusion in W10 here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt/suggestions/6841526-cmd-exe-timeout-errorlevel) hence using `timeout`, the only apparent way would be to save the `%time% before and see whether the`%time% after is 15 sec later - and that's fraught with problems.

`timeout` appears to count the period from invocation to the end of that second as the first second the actually terminate the "second" at ~150ms into the next second (may depend on CPU load.)

Consequently, the timining is, to use a tachnical term, "hairy." That first "second" can be anthing from 150mSec or so to 1150mSec, just add 1000mS for each extra second it's given to timeout (15 sec = 14.15Sec..15.15Sec, for instance)

Possibly a better method would be to use `choice` - reappearing on W7+ AFAIAA. Essentially, that restricts the "interrupting" keyset to alphamerics amd some others - <kbd>Space</kbd> for instance isn't available as a "choice" IIRC.